# 3G dongle can't be metered in windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, 3g

I bought a new Huawei HiLink E3236 3G Dongle with a 10GB/Month data usage limit.
With my Windows 8.1 I consumed nearly 2GB in the first day without using it that much.
I found that I have to put it to metered mode to prevent excessive data usage by the system.
The problem is that this connection doesn't seem to be a wireless connection to be monitored.
It shows as a LAN and there are no opts to change it.
Is there a way to make it work as a wireless network so windows can consider it as a metered network and stop eating my very limited bandwidth.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have installed any required software to use the device.  You might consider removing your personal feelings about Windows from your question as your inability to figure this out on your own does not make Windows rubbish.

Comment: yes the dongle comes with built in plug n play, it connects and everything goes well except that it shows as LAN instead of a wireless connection

Comment: It appears what you want might not be possible with your device and windows 8 does not allow for metered LAN connections but there are third-party solutions.  Technically the device is likely a Ethernet to USB device no reason it should be a wireless connection